# Expiration of zookeeper persistent node

Tags: apache-zookeeper, znodes

I am not able to find information regarding automatic expiration of persistent node in zookeeper. Is persistent node only expire when zookeeper server is shut down or it can expired before before that ?. if yes, what are the possible reason. Here I am asking about automatic expiration not manually deleting the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent ZK nodes are saved on disk and preserved on service restarts and only deleted by request. Ephemeral nodes are deleted automatically on client disconnection.

Comment: suppose i created persistent node on standalone zookeeper server. I restarted the server, will that persistent node can still be accessed on zk server.

Comment: That's correct. See http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.6/zookeeperOver.html#Implementation for details